# How can I know whether RTABmap successfully localized?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running my robot in a localization mode and sometimes I need to know whether the localization was succesfull so I do not need to use PoseEstimate on RViz manually. Is there some specific bool?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327746/how-can-i-know-whether-rtabmap-successfully-localized?/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can add [rtabmap_ros/Info](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#Info_Display) display to RVIZ and look at `Loop closures` and `Proximity detections` values. They should increment when a localization occurs.

Another way from terminal, check values of (not null if localization occurs):

```
$ rostopic echo /rtabmap/info/loopClosureId
$ rostopic echo /rtabmap/info/proximityDetectionId
```

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0